# DB2 query for XML attribute produces: "Error QName=err:XPTY0019"

Tags: database, db2

```
select xmlquery('$MESSAGE/Order/@OrderNo') from yfs_reprocess_error ;
```

`DB2` query for fetching order number attribute from xml (stored in Message column).

While i'm trying to Fetch `XML` data from the database in `DB2` using the below query. Getting error

The result of an intermediate step expression in an `XQuery` path expression contains an atomic value.

```
Error QName=err:XPTY0019..
```

Comment: How does the data look like? See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic14.html#sql16011n

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess your XML structure.
Use the following as an example.

```
select xmlcast(xmlquery('$MESSAGE/Order/@OrderNo' passing MSG as "MESSAGE") as int) 
from (values xmlparse(document '<Order OrderNo="1"/>')) yfs_reprocess_error(MSG);
```

If your XML document has another structure, then please, provide its example.